# Необходимы ли запятые в приведенных предложениях?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Не знаю с чем связано.
Не знаю чего хочу.
Неизвестно откуда пришел.
Дал ему то что нужно.
Забыл где она.

Comment: Это цитаты или часть задания?

Comment: Первое, второе, четвертое предложения взяты из интернета; третье, пятое - предложения собственного сочинения.

Comment: Зачем ответ свой удалил, а? Он был вполне разумен и благоразумен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Необходимы ли запятые в приведенных предложениях?

**В первом, втором, четвёртом и пятом** предложениях запятые нужны.

**В третьем** же всё зависит от того, какое произношение надо отразить на бумаге.

Возможны варианты и с запятой, и без неё:

***Неизвестно, откуда пришел.*** = (Мне, нам, кому-то...) неизвестно...

***Неизвестно откуда пришел.*** = Чёрт (бог, пёс...) знает откуда пришёл.

Пример:

*И вдруг неизвестно кто, **неизвестно откуда пришел** и всю славу опозорил...*

Comment: А я бы не делила предложение запятой: *И вдруг неизвестно кто неизвестно откуда пришёл и всю славу опозорил*. Кто откуда пришёл.

Answer (score 1):

Обычные СПП: **Не знаю, с чем связано. Не знаю, чего хочу. Неизвестно, откуда пришел. Дал ему то, что нужно. Забыл, где она.**

Устойчивые выражения: **пришел неизвестно откуда, набрал кого попало, говорит неизвестно что.**

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146#pp146